# How to disable code completion in NetBeans on Ruby

Tags: ruby, netbeans, netbeans6.8

How do you disable code completion in NetBeans on Ruby?

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm, `Preferences > Editor > Code completion` perhaps?

Comment: The list of languages doesn't include Ruby, do I have to disable to all languages? It seems to have disabled it for Ruby, I'm not 100% sure yet.